# Старницы категорий Bitrix

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, html5, битрикс

Как исключить (удалить) пункт "Каталог" из хлебных крошек на страницах категорий, подкатегорий и товаров в Битрикс?

Comment: Опишите вопрос более подробно? У Вас сайт на битрикс?

Comment: Да сайт на битриксе. Необходимо внести следующие изменения в код сайта:
1) Исключить (удалить) пункт "Каталог" из хлебных крошек на страницах категорий,
подкатегорий и товаров:
Например, для страницы "Дробилки, гребнеотделители и пресса для винограда и
фруктов":
https://casta-vinodelov.com/catalog/01_drobilki_grebneotdeliteli_i_pressa_dlya_vinograda_i
_fruktov/
хлебные крошки должны иметь следующий вид:
Главная > Оборудование для виноделия и переработки фруктов > Дробилки,
гребнеотделители и пресса для винограда и фруктов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В настройках компонентов битрикс есть параметр, отвечающий за внесение этого компонента в навигационную цепочку (ADD_SECTIONS_CHAIN).
Если рассматривать компонент "Каталог", то в хлебные крошки включается раздел и страница карточки товара.

Скорее всего, у вас "Каталог" - это заголовок раздела сайта.

Можете попробовать убрать строку `$sSectionName = "Каталог";` в файле /catalog/.section.php
[Управление пунктами навигационной цепочки](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=3398&LESSON_PATH=3913.4564.4949.4927.3398), но этот вариант повлияет на отображаемое содержимое карты сайта (bitrix:main.map).

В крайнем случае, можете попробовать делать проверку массива $arResult шаблона хлебных крошек и удалять оттуда элемент, в котором `..['TITLE'] == "Каталог";`